# Mvvm light messenger strange working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I think that the question is something weird. But for example i have some code like

```
Messenger.Default.Register<BinarySelectorCommunicator>(this, (emp) => {
    if (emp.Option == ((int)Games.HighLow).ToString())
    {
        DB = null;
        DB = new HigLow();
        DB.Boxes = new ObservableCollection<BoxStruct>();
    }
});
```

It's working well in debug mode compiler enter in each row. but when i am adding new function something like

```
Messenger.Default.Register<BinarySelectorCommunicator>(this, (emp) =>
{
    if (emp.Option == ((int)Games.HighLow).ToString())
    {
        DB = null;
        DB = new HigLow();
        DB.Boxes = new ObservableCollection<BoxStruct>();
        DB.inputAssets = new ObservableCollection<string>((from x in InputData select x.Id).Take(1));
    }
});
```

It does not work. compiler in debug mode does not even enter into messenger. I know that the question weird. why this happen in theory? It's throw exception?

Comment: Can you post the code that sends the message? Can you also confirm that, when testing, you put a breakpoint *on* the if statement and not *inside* the if statemt?

Comment: You need to rewrite your question. Take note that the *compiler* does not run the program, it only checks syntax. Do you mean to say for compiler, "my program"? So it runs in debug mode, what is the other mode which you are running it in which is actually causing the problem. It is not clear what that mode is for us reading this question.